# Test fail with blank page only in Github Actions with Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'contentWindow')

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have a subset of tests that fail every time they run in Github Actions and the screenshots taken are showing they can't find a selector because the page is completely blank.

This issue is only happening in GH Actions but it’s not reproducible on test environments nor local. When running them in local they pass but in the Cypress left side panel there is a log right after a cy.visit that is not present in the CI screenshots:

```
(page load)--page loaded--
(uncaught exception)TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'contentWindow')
```

and in the Chrome console I see this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'contentWindow')
    at $Cypress.eval (tests?p=cypress/support/e2e.js)
```

I should say that "contentWindow" is not part of the tests but I do see "contentWindow" in many places of the SUT.

I tried many custom and configuration timeouts but the page is still blank in CI and I was not able to find why this happens.

Cypress: 10.11.0
Node: 12.16.1
npm: 6.14.2

automation/cypress/dotcom.config.js:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  screenshotOnRunFailure: true,
  viewportWidth: 1920,
  viewportHeight: 1080,
  watchForFileChanges: false,
  fixturesFolder: 'cypress/fixtures/dotcom',
  retries: {
    runMode: 1,
    openMode: 0,
  },
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      return require('./plugins/index.js')(on, config);
    },
    specPattern: 'cypress/integration/dotcom/**',
    excludeSpecPattern: [
      '**/RootsMembershipRCD.feature'
    ],
  },
});
```

automation/cypress/plugins/index.js:

```
const data = require('../../../mr_modules/config/mr_database.json');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const del = require('del');
const {getLastEmailFromFakeEmailInbox} = require('./email-account');
const createBundler = require("@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor");
const preprocessor = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor");
const createEsbuildPlugin = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild");

module.exports = async (on, config) => {
  await preprocessor.addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);
  require('cypress-terminal-report/src/installLogsPrinter')(on, {
    printLogsToConsole:'onFail'
  });

  on("file:preprocessor",
    createBundler({
      plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin.default(config)],
    }));
  on('after:spec', (spec, results) => {
    if (results.stats.failures === 0) {
      if (results.video) {
        del(results.video);
      }
      if (results.screenshots) {
        results.screenshots.forEach((screenshot) => {
          const lastIndex = screenshot.path.lastIndexOf('/');
          const path = screenshot.path.substr(0, lastIndex);
          del(path);
        });
      }
    }
  });

  config.env = process.env;
  return config;
};
```

automation/cypress/support/e2e.js:

```
import './commands';

require('cypress-terminal-report/src/installLogsCollector')();

Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', () => {
  return false;
});

before(function () {
  const env = Cypress.env('env');
  if (env === 'local') {
    cy.fixture("../environmentConfig/local.json").as("environmentConfig");
    cy.get("@environmentConfig").then((environmentConfig) => {
      Cypress.config(environmentConfig);
    });
  } else {
    cy.fixture("../environmentConfig/generic.json").as("environmentConfig");
    cy.get("@environmentConfig").then((environmentConfig) => {
      environmentConfig = JSON.stringify(environmentConfig).replaceAll('{env}', Cypress.env('env'));
      environmentConfig = JSON.parse(environmentConfig);
      Cypress.config(environmentConfig);
    });
  }
});

const app = window.top;

if (!app.document.head.querySelector('[data-hide-command-log-request]')) {
  const style = app.document.createElement('style');
  style.innerHTML =
    '.command-name-request, .command-name-xhr { display: none }';
  style.setAttribute('data-hide-command-log-request', '');

  app.document.head.appendChild(style);
}
```